# Chrome Dev Tools - time elapsed between breakpoints

Tags: breakpoints, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome Developer Tools, after adding two breakpoints in a JavaScript file and executing the whole code, is there any way to measure the time elapsed between them?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [time and timeEnd methods](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoletimelabel) of the console object to log the elapsed time between two points in your code.